# How to add user defined library to ffmpeg compilation

Tags: ffmpeg

I have to plugin my static library(abc.a) to ffmpeg project, So how to place my library in configuration/makefile of ffmpeg to build with my library. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal configure stuff.  Either LDFLAGS environment variable, or a configure option (`--extra-ldflags=-labc`) (though your static file should be named libabc.a, FWIW).

If libabc.a is in "some other folder" then you will have to/need to add the folder to the configure as well, like

`--extra-ldflags='-L/path/to/my/library -labc'`

If your library is installed to the system path you shouldn't need the directory adder.

Also make sure its got the same "binding" (basically, libabc.a needs to be all C code, if it is C++ code then "surrounding" the method Fun_abc you will need and `extern "C" {` block.
GL!

Comment: thanks for your feedback, the ffmpeg configure with -labc lib is done, but there is linking issue, it is able to link library function ffmpeg. while make the ffmpeg, it is getting Error: unresolved external symbol Fun_abc();  { Fun_abc() is function in library libabc.a }

Comment: added more description here.  Unfortunately if this doesn't work there may not be much more I can do to help.